# Why keycloak not working in IE and Safari?

Tags: reactjs, keycloak

So, I have implemented keycloak with reactjs and it works fine in chrome but when I try to run it in IE or in safari it does not even sign in. i.e I get an error as Invalid user. it's same as in safari and in IE.

Attached the pic of error[image: error page]

Following is my react code for initialising the keycloak.

```
import Keycloak from "keycloak-js";
const kc = new Keycloak({
  realm: "claro",
  url: "URL",
  "ssl-required": "none",
  resource: "apps",
  "public-client": true,
  "verify-token-audience": true,
  "use-resource-role-mappings": true,
  "confidential-port": 0,
  clientId: "apps"
  // "clientSecret":"",
  // "enable-cors": true
});
let app = (
  <HashRouter basename={"/"}>
    <div>
      <Route
        exact
        path="/"
        render={props => {
          return <UI {...props} kc={kc} />;
        }}
      />
      <Route
        exact
        path="/rms"
        render={props => {
          return <Rms {...props} kc={kc} />;
        }}
      />

      <Route
        exact
        path="/iaasmobile"
        render={props => {
          return <Iaasmobile {...props} kc={kc} />;
        }}
      />
    </div>
  </HashRouter>
);
kc.init({ onLoad: "login-required",checkLoginIframe: false })
  .success(authenticated => {
    // console.log(authenticated, kc);
    if (authenticated) {
      ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById("root"));
    }
  })
  .error(e => {
    Swal({
      type: "error",
      title: "Error Authentication"
    });
  });
```

P.S

just a FYI that when i replaced my URL to the IP address of the URN it works.
i.e `url:"//sso.asd.com/auth"` to `url:"//13.23.45.67/auth"`

Comment: Did you look at the requests in your browser debugging tools? What is different when compared to Chrome?

Comment: The request is the same. All the values configured in keycloak object are being passed in params